# Program Files (x86) problem

Tags: windows, installation

I have an installer package, at the last step user can select launch application or not. the installed application is 32bit, during the installation we select the installation folder to "c:\Program Files", while it will always install application to "c:\Program Files(x86)" folder, then we meet problem, we can not launch the application, we have tested that if we choose the default installation folder(which means c:\program files") it works well. so I guess the problem is that windows launch 32bit application as 64bit, so it failed. how to solve it?

Comment: There's not enough detail here. Could you expand.

Comment: Is your app 32-bit or 64-bit? What do you mean by "we can not launch the application", exact error message or description of symptoms please.

Comment: first my application is 32bit, then I want to install my application to 64bit system and launch it when the installation finished(there is a checkbox at last page), by default in window7 64bit OS there will be two folder "Program Files(x86)", which is for 32bit application. "Program Files" folder is for 64bit application. when I install my application I modify the default installation path to "Program Files", then I could not launch my application anymore

Answer (score 0):

Your installer should know the path the application was installed to. You should use it, your EXE file key; for a WiX example see [Well Done](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson8.php#8.6) section of the tutorial.

If your installer package is MSI-based, then the installer is a 64 bit process, and it sees both *Program Files (x86)* and *Program Files*. I think it is the problem why you can't start your program. (A 32 bit executable will see only *Program Files (x86)* under the name of *Program Files*).